# When I try to upload new changeset, "resolving deltas" never ends

Tags: git, gerrit

When I tried to upload new changeset, "resolving deltas" stage never ends.
There are no error/sshd log at gerrit server.

```
xxx@power:~/src/bems_repo/src/bems$ repo upload bms/bms
Upload project src/bms/ to remote branch master:
  branch xxx_gerrit_error ( 2 commits, Mon Jul 23 21:34:19 2012 +0900):
         731ec772 fixture json modified
         3106afab xxx large fixtures
to xxx.com:8080 (y/N)? y
Counting objects: 124, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (54/54), done.
Writing objects: 100% (70/70), 9.66 MiB | 723 KiB/s, done.
Total 70 (delta 59), reused 24 (delta 16)
remote: Resolving deltas:   3% (2/59)    <= stop at 3%. never ends.
```

gerrit server's top status is like below

```
PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
2068 gerrit2   20   0 1240m 961m  11m S  200 31.9 131:32.33 java
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a Java thread dump and post that to the [Gerrit discussion group](http://groups.google.com/group/repo-discuss).  To take a thread dump, find the PID of the java process and then execute "jstack $PID"